# PHP Redirect without affecting headers

Tags: php, header, web, http-headers

I'm trying to create a PHP script that will always be called on every page load, without altering existing code of a website, and as little extra configurations as possible.

Here's my problem, I do not want it to effect anything regarding the actual requests (headers). Here is the desired flow:

Request-> somescript.php -> Actual destination

So, I cannot use the header() function, and the solution has to be completely server side.

I was thinking, after the script completes it's task, it could include/require the PHP file that was intended.

Any ideas/suggestions would be really appreciated.

Regards,

Branden Martin

PS: I cannot use php_value inside of the .htaccess file as will sometimes be used in a CGI environment.

Bottom line: Need some code to run on every server request

Comment: So, you can't change ini options such as [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/auto_prepend_file)?

Answer (score 0):

You want a script to be executed before any other scripts? If you uses Apache I can think of one possible solution... if you can rewrite in `.htaccess`...

`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test
RewriteRule !(common.php) common.php/$1
```

`common.php`:

```
<?php
$request=substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],6);
if($request==""){
    $request="index.php";
}
if(substr($request,0,1)=="/"){
    // Prevent browsing local files (*nix)
    header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden",true,403);
}else if(!file_exists($request)){
    // Not found
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found",true,404);
}else{
    // Request URI should be valid
    do_what_you_want_to_do_before_anything_else();
    // Include the original request URI...
    if(substr($request,-4)==".php"){
        include $request;
    }else{
        // Prevent executing non-PHP code
        echo file_get_contents($request);
    }
}
?>
```

There is still much code to write, including security measures and changing the `$_SERVER` array if the child scripts cares.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the servers' php.ini perhaps you can use the [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive?

You need to be careful though: If you add it directly to the .ini it is active for all sites hosted by that webserver. You can also add it via the php_value in apache or php-fpm to do it on a per site bases, or you can build in a site detection in your script.

In terms of of easiness in configuring it, you can't get it much simpler.